# math question help differential equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

We have a line which passes from the point (1:2).The Abscissa of the intersection of the  tangent(of the line)  with x-axis is two times smaller than the Abscissa of the intersection of the tangent and the line..How to do this? a little hint?

Comment: What do you mean by "x-axis," "Ox," and "two times smaller"? What "tangent" are you talking about?

Comment: By two times smaller ( sorry Im not native) I mean for example we have the number 2. 2 is two times smaller than 4. Two times smaller means  "  dividing by two"

Comment: Instead of two times smaller, say half.

Comment: The tangent of the line? Isn't that just the line itself?

Comment: If you're having trouble translating the problem into English, you might want to add the problem in the original language to your question, and include the tag [(translation-request)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/translation-request), in addition to the (differential-equations) tag.

Answer (score 1):

My translation of the question:

> We have a curve which passes through the point $(1,2)$. The abscissa of the intersection of any tangent to this curve with the $x$-axis is two times smaller than the abscissa of the point of tangency. How to find this curve?

Let $x_0$ be the abscissa of the point of tangency. Then the tangent line has the equation $y=f(x_0)+f'(x_0)(x-x_0)$. To find where this line crosses the $x$-axis, equate $y$ to zero: 
$$ 0 = f(x_0)+f'(x_0)(x-x_0)$$
The solution is $x_1= x_0-f(x_0)/f'(x_0) $. Since we are told that $x_1=x_0/2$, it follows that $f(x_0)/f'(x_0) = x_0/2$. This holds for every $x_0$. Therefore, $f$ satisfies the differential equation 
$$ \frac{f(x)}{f'(x)} = \frac{x}{2} \tag1 $$
which is not very hard to solve (it's separable).